# prove that - **if $ \ A , \ B \ $ are congruent then $ \ f(A)=f(B) \ $**

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \ A \in F^{n \times n } \ $ be a symmetric matrix over the field $ F \ $ . Define $ \ f(A)=\{x^2 \ det (A) \ | \ x \in F \} \ $.

Then prove that - **if $ \ A , \ B \ $ are congruent then $ \ f(A)=f(B) \ $**

**Answer:**

Since $ A , B \ $ are congruent to each other , there is an invertible matrix $ P \ $ such that

$ B=PAP^{-1} \\  \Rightarrow det(B)=det(PAP^{-1})=det(PP^{-1}) det (A) \\ \Rightarrow x^2 det(B)=x^2  det(A) , \\ \Rightarrow f(A)=f(B)  $

**Am I right ?**

Comment: No. For one thing, congruence would be $B = P A P^T$

Comment: so can i do this using the new definition of yours ?

Answer (score 2):

A is symmetric so $A^T = A$, if $\quad B = PAP^T$ then

$$det(B) =det(PAP^T) = det(P)det(AP^T) = det(P)det((AP^T)^T)) = det(P)det(PA^T) $$

$$= det(P)^2det(A^T)=det(P)^2 *det(A) = x^2det(A) $$

so that

$y^2det(B) = (yx)^2 det(A) \in f(A)$

Now all that's left is the other direction.